# Значение недопустимо большое для int32 (при типе real)

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
procedure dec_bin(**a:real**);    
var wstr,mdstr:string;i,lng:integer;b,c,md:real;    
begin    
  repeat    
    **b:=a/2;**    
    c:=frac(b);  
    if c=0 then md:=0 else md:=1;  
    str(md,mdstr);  
    wstr:=concat(wstr,mdstr);  
    **a:=trunc(b);**  
  until a=1;  
  wstr:=concat(wstr,'1');  
  lng:=length(wstr);  
  for i:=lng downto 1 do  
  binstr:=concat(binstr,wstr[i]);  
end;
```

При вводе 'a' с более чем 10 разрядами выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка времени выполнения: Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32.

Comment: Уточните, на какой строке вознивает ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка возникает на строке `a:=trunc(b)`.

Comment: То есть вы имеете ввиду,что `b` выходит за рамки типа int32 или что функция trunc приводит переменную к целочисленному типу в результате обрезания знаков после точки?

Comment: У меня же `b` описано как вещественная переменная

Comment: Посмотрите справку по `Trunc` в Паскале. В делфи происходит именно так (*функция trunc приводит переменную к целочисленному типу в результате обрезания знаков после точки*), только в Делфи это int64.

Answer (score 0):

`a:=trunc(b);` приводит число с точкой к целому. По умолчанию, видимо, это int32 (32-битное целое). По смыслу, int32 может вместить только числа из диапазона -2³¹ .. +2³¹-1.

Вероятно у вас `b` выходит за диапазон, отсюда и ошибка.